# How to force word wrap on table with width auto?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Reading some previous post I came to know about that to wrap text in table we need to add `table-layout: fixed` and `word-wrap: break-word`. But this is not working if there isn't any fixed width to table

```css
.container {

  width: 30%;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #888;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  }

.table {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="table">
  <a href="#">unbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabel</a>
</div>
  
  </div>
```

On my website I have a sort of situation where I cannot give fixed width to element with display table.

How do I achieve line breaks so as text don't overflow?

Comment: @Pete In actual website it bootstrap columns width has width in percentages. I added fixed width here to avoid unnecessary markup. I have changed it to percentage in question itself now.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the CSS property `word-break` to do this.

`word-break: break-all` breaks all cells content to multiple lines to fit the width.

```
.table {
   display: table;
   table-layout: fixed;
   width: auto;
   word-break: break-all;
}
```

Check http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp for other values of the property.

Answer (score 0):

Try with giving the .table element **width** and the anchor element **word-wrap: break-word;**

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #888;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
.table {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%
}
a {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="table">
    <a href="#">unbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabelunbreajabel</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @user31782 Please check now , it should work on firefox as well.